# Create dummy payload for CdkDragDrop event

Tags: angular, jestjs, jasmine

I want to unit test a method, in angular+jest:

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      let clonedData: any = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.item.data));
      clonedData.paramId = this.IDGenerator() + '_' + event.currentIndex;
      this.formCtrls.splice(event.currentIndex, 0, clonedData)
    }
    this.selectedControl = this.formCtrls[event.currentIndex];
  }
```

Is it possible to create a dummy payload for `CdkDragDrop<string[]>`, so that i can call this method with given payload.

Comment: You can always cast your parameter in your test, e.g. `myComp.drop('foo' as CdkDragDrop<string[]>)`.

Comment: @DonJuwe, can you plz elaborate little more, how to do that. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Type Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to cast your input parameter to whatever you want it to be, e.g.:

```
const myEvent = {'foo': 'bar'} as CdkDragDrop<string[]>;
myComp.drop(myEvent);
```

Doing so, your test should compile.

Comment: sure, will try that, thanks